# Парсинг данных и yaml в python

Tags: python, yaml

Всем привет. Как я могу распарсить данный из yaml в функцию, чтоб передавать ключ и значение. суть в том, что на выходе мне нужно получить для бесконечно возможного количества новых service1...99 вывод вида : `service1 google good http://google.com 1 1 app1`, `service2 google bad http://gooogle.com 2 2 app2` и так далее. это вообще возможно сделать и что я делаю не так? мой код работает не так и я не знаю куда копать

```yaml
services:
  service1:
    name: google good
    url: http://google.com
    service: 1
    time: 1
  service2:
    name: google bad
    url: http://gooogle.com
    service:  2
    time:  2
  service3:
    name: google bad
    url: http://googgle.com
    service:  3
    time:  3
```

в который я подставляю данные url, который хочу проверить на доступность кодом

```
def get_status_app():
    with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
        config = yaml.load_all(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        config_services =  config["url"]
        print(config_services)
        for urls in config_url :            
            app_url(urls)
    
def app_url(urls):
        try:
            resp = requests.head(urls)
            if resp.status_code == 200:
                print(urls,'app1')
            else:
                print('app2')
        except:
            print(urls,'app3')

get_status_app()
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что urlы вложены в service_name (service1, service2 etc), поэтому они не будут доступны. В начале вам нужно узнать service_name, а уже потом вытаскиваете из него url, name etc. Попробуйте код ниже:

```
def get_status_app():
    with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
        dump = yaml.load_all(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        for service_name in dump:
            config = dump[service_name]
            name = config['name']
            url = config['url']
            service = config['service']
            time = config['time']
```

> @ Dmitrii Seleznev
> а если будет еще один общий заголовок в yaml services и дальше уже service1..etc

Представьте yaml файл в виде дерева или проще словаря, где значением может быть еще один словарь.
Вы вытаскиваете из services значения `services = dump['services']`, а дальше итерируетесь по ним, узнавая `service_name`, только точка входа в значения  `service_name` (url, name etc) будет уже `services[service_name]`.

```
def get_status_app():
    with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
        dump = yaml.load_all(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        services = dump['services']
        for service_name in services:
            config = services[service_name]
            name = config['name']
            url = config['url']
            service = config['service']
            time = config['time']
```

Наглядная структура вложенности в виде дерева:

```
services
└── service_name(service1)
    └── url
        └── google.com
```

Comment: а если будет еще один общий заголовок в  yaml `services` и дальше уже `service1..etc`

Comment: Логика такая же, как с сервисами. Вы вытаскиваете из "заголовка" данные header_name = dump['header_name'] и дальше итерируетесь по нему узнавая service_name, только точка входа в данныe от service_name будет header_name[service_name]. Представьте yaml файл деревом (он таким и является), а вы просто переходите с одной ветки на другую. В комментариях нормально кодом не написать, надеюсь понятно объяснила.

Comment: не очень понял, но сейчас попробую протестировать, если есть время и возможность попробуйте изменить ваш ответ, я просто совсем новичок в питоне и пока понимание дается очень трудно :(

Comment: Работает! Екатерина, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Не за что, успехов в изучении Python. ;)

Comment: @КатеринаБелокрыльцева код из комментариев лучше перенести в сам ответ, так он лучше читается. Комментарии не подходят для размещения блоков кода.

Comment: @insolor Я в курсе, что комментарии не для этого, это был код под доп. вопрос. Перенесла по вашей просьбе код в основной ответ.